# SSIS Export to Excel destination uses header coloring

Tags: excel, ssis

I have a series of Data Flow Tasks taking results from SQL and loading them into a Excel file. The Excel file is copied from a template using a File System Task, and includes a color coded header row for each sheet being loaded.

The issue I am having is that any cells populated by SSIS are pulling the background color and formatting from what appears to be a random header cell from a random worksheet. Which header cell and sheet changes when I save changes to the template, but I can't get SSIS to fill using plain black text and white background.

Is there some step I can take when saving the template to insure the formatting is clear for SSIS?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem - did you ever resolve this ? I had it working by inserting a table for the header rows but now it won't write to the row below the 'header' and will only start inserting data at the next row !

Comment: I have not. To resolve I have had to stip all formatting from the report.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I was able to resolve this by making some adjustments to the template excel file. Look at the column A on your template file, you most likely don't have it mapped in the SSIS excel destination. Change the color to white (or no color) and it will solve the problem.